# OpenCv, composeRT giving strange results

Tags: opencv

I have an openCv application that finds fiducial markers. What i want to do is get the relative transformation between these markers, in marker space.

The markers are all on the same plane, in a line, with different rotations, like this:

[image: marker placement]

The first marker found, I set the following variables as my 'Origin' or zero point.

```
cv::Mat otv(OriginTvec); //the first marker found, translation
cv::Mat orv(OriginRvec); //rotation vector
```

Then, for the next marker, i run this:

```
cv::Mat composedT, composedR;
relativePosition(orv, otv, rvec, tvec, composedR, composedT); //rvec, tvec are the current marker transforms
```

with these functions:

```
void inversePerspective(cv::Mat rvec, cv::Mat tvec, cv::Mat &invRvec, cv::Mat &invTvec)
{
    cv::Mat R;
    cv::Rodrigues(rvec, R);
    R = R.t();
    invTvec = -R * tvec;
    cv::Rodrigues(R, invRvec);  
}


void relativePosition(cv::Mat rvec1, cv::Mat tvec1, cv::Mat rvec2, cv::Mat tvec2, cv::Mat &composedRvec, cv::Mat &composedTvec)
{
    // Inverse the second marker, the right one in the image
    cv::Mat invRvec, invTvec, orgRvec, orgTvec;
    inversePerspective(rvec2, tvec2, invRvec, invTvec);

    cv::composeRT(rvec1, tvec1, invRvec, invTvec, composedRvec, composedTvec);

}
```

That should give me the relative transformation from one marker to another in the `composedR` and `composedT` matrices.

When i print the results, it works well for one marker, and yet not for another.

marker ID 10: (correct result)

```
 Origin Tvec:: [17.40034702383909; 0.9026984362994943; 97.32508809945712]

marker 10 tvec: [4.461679451405943; 0.6087983984519095; 97.92729032119958]

relative transform:: [12.94176130094641; -0.5101704536674134; -0.329672315462247]
```

marker id 11: (incorrect result)

```
Origin Tvec: [17.40034702383909; 0.9026984362994943; 97.32508809945712]

marker 11 tvec: [-8.965452763369187; 1.030574874942149; 96.66721684253494]

relative transform: [-0.9334416873257574; -26.34493062970068;0.8233238281594311]
```

It looks as if the axes are switched in the incorrect result. But where am i going wrong here?

I have checked the initial returned marker transforms, and they are correct, so it is an issue with the above functions.

Comment: By the pictures, it looks like 1 of them has a different coordinate system... probably there comes your switched axes :) check the euler angles as well, probably you will see ~90°  around the z axis

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. They are all from the cv::aruco library, the coordinate systems should be the same!

Comment: yes, it is the same, but one marker is rotated 90° around z axis, as you can see in your sample image. This will affect the relative transformation result. Try it with rvec being [0,0,0] in both cases, and you should get something closer to the expected result

Comment: Ah, indeed I do! Thank you. How can i check for this happening in my code? The markers will not always be on the same plane

Comment: Well a relative transformation counting the angle seems correct, even if it makes it look like if the axes are swapped. What is your goal at the end? compare the translation part only?

Comment: I want to get the relative transform between a few markers, randomly placed around the room. Not on the same plane. i need rotation and translation. So I really need to know if the axes are swapped, so that i can correct it.

Comment: could it be that the marker is actually rotated 90°? then the current results make sense and there should not be a need to correct them.

Comment: It does have a different rotation, yes. the red squares at the corners indicate the first corner point, and therefore rotation on the plane. Is it that the `composeRT` function is rotating and then translating?  So i could perhaps subtract the rotational difference between the origin marker and the new marker before i `composeRT` to get the coordinates in the correct world space?

Comment: Looking at the image again, the far right marker(17) is the origin. The correct one is actually 10, which has the obvious rotation. The other one, which looks to have the same rotation, is incorrect!

Comment: It looks like what i am seeing is this: `https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8813` which is a known problem with 4 point PnP solving it seems. i will keep looking into it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, when the points are in the same plane, it can be ambiguous, since it could be also generated by another rotation, but your problem looks more like the symbol being physically rotated. This ambiguity could change the sign of an axis.

Comment: How can I cope with this physical rotation? Perhaps I can write my own composeRT that translates first, and then rotates? Does that sound valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178592/discussion-between-api55-and-anti).